# Makefile on Linux and Cygwin

Tags: linux, makefile, cygwin

I'm developing a little command-line tool for a friend. I'm on linux, but he's on Windows and I want to make the compilation process easy for him, as he's not used to having to compile stuff himself.

Building the tool works flawlessly, but now I want to add an 'install' target to the Makefile that copies the binary to his cygwin64/bin folder, which is (supposed to be) on his path. However, I want the Makefile to still run under linux. Is there a generic approach to his? Or should I grep, sed, cut and awk my way through the PATH string and extract the folder I'm looking for?

Comment: Why would you not build it yourself and package it in an MSI instead?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That doesn't really help with the problem which is the install bit. He would still need to get the path he wants somehow (or let the person pick graphically I suppose).

Comment: Use `binpath=$(dirname "$(command -v $some_program)")` where `$some_program` is the name something that lives in the directory you want to get the path you need from?

Comment: I could have sworn that Windows had this dedicated directory where programs should usually be installed. You know, somewhere to put the files. The program's files.

Comment: Inside cygwin, /usr/bin is the same thing as C:\....\cygwin64\bin. You can just install to /usr/bin

Comment: @Ignacio No need to be sarcastic man. The program files directory isn't on the cygwin path, so that won't work. And that wasn't the question. I want to know if there is a generic way to implement the install target. It should work under Linux and Cygwin (and Mac). I think Etan is on to something though... I could just take the path to `ls` I suppose :-)

Comment: @Markku Really? I thought I checked this, amd bash complained that it didn't exist. Maybe I used the wrong slash... I still don't know if the Cygwin shell expects the Unix or Windows slash :-p I will look into this some more.

Comment: Cygwin wants unix / slashes